# How to manage code base while unbundling a iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, github

If I want to unbundle an existing app into two apps and while still providing same functionalities in base app. eg. FB messenger existing as separate app but FB app also provide that functionality. So how to manage code base in that scenario ?
So its like if do some changes it will reflect in base app features as well as unbundled app as well.

Answer (score 1):

1) Start by splitting code base into three folders in project: App A, App B and a Shared.

2) Once you have the three folders, split them into 3 Xcode projects in a single workspace, to ensure they really are independent. A and B would be standalone app targets that reference the shared project as a static library.

3) After that, split the workspace into two separate workspaces that both use the "Shared" static library. You could make the shared stuff into a CocoaPod if you're so inclined. Put any shared image resources, nibs etc in a folder imported by both projects.

Answer (score 1):

a) For iOS apps, one option is to remove common code into a private pod project, then have two app projects that use this pod.

As in your example, make an "FB messaging" pod, then make FB app and FB Messenger app depend on "FB messaging" pod.

b) If you don't use pods (and you should), you still can make separate static library with common code, and two projects that depend on that static library.

c) Third option could be just removing common code into a separate directory on local disk, and referencing code from that directory from the two app projects.